# Prolog - sum of numbers in a list

Tags: list, prolog

I'm very new to Prolog and still struggling with the syntax of the language. I'm trying to write a functor that looks through a list and creates a new list with the head being the sum of all the numbers of the list, and the tail being whatever else was in it.

For example, [1,2,a,3,b,c,4] = [10,a,b,c].

Right now, I fear my code is very crude, but if someone could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
sumOfNumbers([X], Z) :-
    number(X),
    Z is Z+X.
sumOfNumbers([X], _) :-
    not(number(X)).
sumOfNumbers([X|Rest], Z) :-
    number(X),
    Z is Z+X,
    sumOfNumbers(Rest, Z).
sumOfNumbers([X|Rest], Z) :-
    not(number(X)),
    sumOfNumbers(Rest, Z).
```

Hopefully this is not entirely off base. Thanks again

Comment: in Prolog, Z is Z+X can be true only if X=0

Answer (score 0):

I would take this approach: 
Separate the given list to two lists of numbers  and letters, sum up the numbers and append to the list of letters:

```
% Sum of list of numbers
% sum(+List, -Sum)
sum([], 0).
sum([H|T], S) :-
    sum(T, S1),
    S is H + S1.

% Separate a list into two lists one of numbers and second of non-numbers
% separate(+InputList, -Numbers, -Letters)
separate([], [], []).
separate([H|T], [H|N], L) :- 
    number(H),
    separate(T, N, L).
separate([H|T], N, [H|L]) :- 
    separate(T, N, L).

% This is your function
sumOfNumbers(L, [Sum | Letters]) :-
    separate(L, Numbers, Letters),
    sum(Numbers, Sum).
```

This is not most optimal approach, but it is logically straightforward and clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are using to few variables. Prolog is a declarative language, you can't change a variable once it it is set. As [CapeliiC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874024/capellic) has pointed out, `Z is Z + X` only is true if `X = 0`. For that reason, most documentation of predicates start with `true if xxxx/y unifies with…`.

The base case for List recursions is in most cases the empty list `[]`, not the one element list `[X]`. It just complicates your program in most cases, or even worse, adds solutions after backtracking.

These are the cases you'll need to handle while walking through the list.

1. The list is empty → return a list `[0]`
2. The head is a number → return the previous result plus the found number
3. The head isn't a number → add it to the list after the number of the previous result.

This way, you always make sure that you have a number as the first element to the output list. The predicate would be nicer written as `sumOfNumbers(Input, Sum, Rest)` don't get distracted by the fact that the first element is just another argument.

so here is the program:

```
sumOfNumbers([],[0]).
sumOfNumbers([X|R],[Z|A]):-
    number(X),               % cut here
    sumOfNumbers(R,[Y|A]),
    Z is Y + X.
sumOfNumbers([X|R],[Y,X|A]):-
    \+ number(X),            % cut here
    sumOfNumbers(R,[Y|A]).
```

You can add (green) cut operators after the number checks to prevent a failing redo.

I personally prefer to use the `->` operator if both cases of a check occur and the structure is similar:

```
sumOfNumbers2([],[0]). 
sumOfNumbers2([X|R],Out):-
    sumOfNumbers2(R,[Y|A]),
    (number(X)->             % read as if X is a number
       Z is Y + X,
       Out = [Z|A];
     Out =[Y, X|A]).
```

Answer (score 0):

In prolog, once you've bound a variable to a value, it *ceases to be variable*. That means you need to maintain state on the call stack as you recurse down your list. So I'd approach the problem like this, using a *helper predicate* with extra paramaters that maintain state as we go.

the convention is often for the helper to have the same functor as the "public" predicate, with the extra values needed to maintain state. I would approach it something like this:

```
sum_of_numbers(Xs,Ys) :-     % to sum the numbers in a list, 
  sum_of_numbers(Xs,0,[],Ys) % we invoke the helper, seeding its two accumulators appropriately.
  .

sum_of_numbers( []     , T , L , [T|L] ) .  % when the source list isexhausted, unify the accumulators with the result
sum_of_numbers( [X|Xs] , T , L , R     ) :- % otherwise,
  number(X) ,                               % - if X is numeric
  T1 is T+X ,                               % - increment the tally
  sum_of_numbers(Xs,T1,L,R)                 % - and recurse down
  .                                         %
sum_of_numbers( [X|Xs] , T , L , R     ) :- % otherwise,
  \+ number(X) ,                            % - if X is non-numeric
  sum_of_numbers(Xs,T,[X|L],R)              % - add X to the list accumulator
  .                                         % - and recurse down.
```

You can also use a soft cut (implication) to combine clauses 2 and 3:

```
sum_of_numbers( []     , T , L , [T|L] ) .
sum_of_numbers( [X|Xs] , T , L , R     ) :-
  ( number(X) ->
    T1 is T+X , L1 = L
  ;
    T1 = T    , L1 = [X|L]
  ) ,
  sum_of_numbers(Xs,T1,L1,R)
  .
```

Whether this is an improvement or not is up to you.